# Oracle Apex login Twice on the Same App, Machine and Broswer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I don't know if this is possible but. Is it possible to login twice on the same user on the same app in the same browser.

Reason for this is to allow users visibly 2 full pages at once without have to flick between pages. 
This would be displayed over 2 screens.

I know you can use IE for one page and say Chrome for the other. This gets around the cookie/session issues. Or I could create multi users user1-1 & user1-2 for example but that's not a good option to use.

Comment: Why not just right-click on the link and select "open in new tab"?

Comment: That will only bring back a blank page, same as a open in new window

Comment: Yes, it's possible - but the user may encounter state issues in some apps if they try to do things in both windows (e.g. edit a record in one screen, then edit another record in the other screen). Generally it should work fine if one screen is just left open for viewing purposes, and the other is used for actually posting changes.

Comment: Another alternative is to use the In-Private browsing feature of the browser. One session could be a "normal" session, the other would be a private browsing session - they won't share cookies and will use independent apex sessions.